# Android - Views with alignParentBottom = "true" are not visibles in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm implementing an app with `Toolbar`, `TabLayout`, `ViewPager` and `CoordinatorLayout`. The property `layout_behavior = "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in ViewPager causes an **extra space in the bottom** as illustrated.

How I can I put views with `alignParentBottom = "true"` in the ViewPager and that they are visible and not hidden in the part that is not visible? Thank you

[image]

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:translationZ="2dp"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/tabs_text_selector"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Have you got the solution for this. I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove

```
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

inside android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
                    app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"/>

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:translationZ="2dp"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/tabs_text_selector"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a test"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here, `TextView` position is at the bottom of the `DrawerLayout`.